# Why does a horizontal scroll-bar appear when adding small div below HTML Canvas?

Tags: html, css, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a simple HTML `canvas` that covers the entire page which displays fine by itself.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
window.addEventListener("resize",
  function() {
    canvas.width = innerWidth;
    canvas.height = innerHeight;  
  }
);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#mainCanvas {
  display: block;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<canvas id = "mainCanvas"></canvas>
```

However, when I try to add a `div` element below it, immediately a *horizontal* scroll bar appears even though all of the elements are less than the total width (and therefore there shouldn't be any horizontal overflow). For example:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("mainCanvas");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
window.addEventListener("resize",
  function() {
    canvas.width = innerWidth;
    canvas.height = innerHeight;  
  }
);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#mainCanvas {
  display: block;
  background-color: blue;
}

#info {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<canvas id = "mainCanvas"></canvas>
<div id = "info"></div>
```

I know I can fix the problem of the horizontal scrollbar showing up by using `overflow-x: hidden` but I want to understand why it appears in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is unrelated to `<canvas>` and the behavior is the same with any other block element such as a `<div>`.

If you set the lone element in the `<body>`'s dimensions to `innerWidth`/`innerHeight` and the parent `<body>` has no padding or margin, then you've used up exactly all of the space on the page and no scrollbars are necessary.

If you add a `<div>` below your full-page element, a vertical scrollbar becomes necessary to allow the user to move the viewport down to see it. But this new vertical scrollbar now takes up some horizontal space that is ignored by `innerWidth`, as the [docs state](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/innerWidth):

> `innerWidth` returns the interior width of the window in pixels. This includes the width of the vertical scroll bar, if one is present.

The original element set to exactly `innerWidth` pixels now overflows the screen horizontally by the width of the vertical scrollbar. Therefore, a horizontal scrollbar becomes necessary.

An option you can try is `document.documentElement.clientWidth`. As the [docs state](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientWidth):

> `clientWidth` [...] includes padding but excludes borders, margins, and vertical scrollbars (if present).

(you might need to click 'full page' after running the snippet to see the difference):

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("main-canvas");
canvas.width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
canvas.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
window.addEventListener("resize", // TODO debounce
  function () {
    canvas.width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    canvas.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;  
  }
);
```

```css
body {
  background-color: red;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#main-canvas {
  display: block;
  background-color: blue;
}

#info {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="main-canvas"></canvas>
<div id="info"></div>
```

See also [How to get the browser viewport dimensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8876069/6243352)