# Hello! Could someone help to find out how to make vue swiper work only at mobile screen?

Tags: vue.js, swiper.js

I have to make vue slider(swiper) work only at mobile screen and destroy it at computer screen.

I would appreciate if someone help me to resolve it.

Here is my vue code below.

```
<template>
  <section>
    <Swiper>
      <SwiperSlide>
        Slide_1
      </SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>
        Slide_2
      </SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>
        Slide_3
      </SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>
        Slide_4
      </SwiperSlide>
      <SwiperSlide>
        Slide_5
      </SwiperSlide>
    </Swiper>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/vue/swiper-vue.js';

import 'swiper/swiper.scss';
import 'swiper/modules/navigation/navigation.scss';
import 'swiper/modules/pagination/pagination.scss'; 

export default {
  name: "VueSwiperCarousel",
  data:{
    return {

    }
  },
  components: {
    Swiper,
    SwiperSlide
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a couple of ways to do so. I assume the simplest one is to hide your swiper on bigger screens using css media queries.

```
<template>
  ...
  <Swiper class="swiper">...</Swiper>
  ...
</template>

<style>
@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) {
  .swiper {
    dispay: none
  }
}
</style>
```

Probably a more performant solution is to detect viewport width in js (check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248081/how-to-get-the-browser-viewport-dimensions))