# Screen.width property return always the same value that is not the width of the screen

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I try to develop a block *WordPress* using *webpack*. In the *save.js* file, I try to get the with of the user’s screen to choose the content of the return

I used *screen.widh* or *window.innerWidth*. Both return a value without any link with the different devices
I tried also to use hooks that give  the width when resize. They give the same results.

Could you help me ?

I Said what I hâve tried. I don’t understand what happens. I would like have explanations and, if possible, a solution

I've found a French-English translator and would like to clarify my subject.
1 - the results given by *screen.width* and *window.innerwidth* are always the same, whatever the device used.
2 - the *alert()* functions linked to *onclick* give a correct result.
I'll share my code below:

```
import { useBlockProps, InnerBlocks } from '@wordpress/block-editor';
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import React from 'react';
import useScreenSize from './useScreenSize';

export default function save(props) {

    const blockProps = useBlockProps.save();
    const { petitsEcransSeulement, seuilPetitEcran, simuEcran,  } = props.attributes;
    const screenSize = 1949;
    const screenWidth = 1944;
    // Déterminer si le texte doit être rétracté en fonction de la largeur de l'écran et de la valeur de petitsEcransSeulement
    const retractable = (petitsEcransSeulement && screenWidth < parseInt(seuilPetitEcran)) || !petitsEcransSeulement;
    
    const classExtension = retractable ? 'wp-block-group hide-extension' : 'wp-block-group';
    var ts0=screen.width;
    var ts1=0;
    var tw1=0;
    var tw0 = () => {
        const lg = window.innerWidth;
        return lg;
        }
    
    return (
        <div {...blockProps}>
            <div name="extension" className={classExtension}>
                <InnerBlocks.Content />
            </div>
            {tw1 = window.innerWidth} {ts1 = screen.width}
            <div>ts0 : {ts0}<br/>
            ts1 : {ts1}<br/>
            tw0 : {tw0()}<br/>
            tw1 : {tw1}<br/>
            </div>
            {retractable && (
                <button
                    className="bouton-extension-retraction"
                    value= "on" //{ etatInitialRetraction } 
                    onClick="jQuery(this.previousElementSibling).toggle(2000); (this.value == 'on') ? (this.firstChild.className = 'fas fa-angle-up', this.value = 'off') : (this.firstChild.className = 'fas fa-angle-down', this.value = 'on');
                    "
                >
                    <i className="fas fa-angle-down"> </i>
                </button>
            )}
            {(parseInt(window.innerWidth) >= parseInt(600)) ? (
            <div>{screenWidth}  Grand écran</div>) : (
            <div>{window.innerWidth} Petit écran</div>)
                
            }
            <button onclick="ts0 = screen.width; alert(window.innerWidth);alert(test.width);alert({retractable})">Largeur écran</button>
        </div>
    );
}
```

I spent many hours trying to figure out why my code wasn't working. I tried to get help from chatGPT ;-(
I added test variables to check what *screen.width* and *window.innerwidth* were telling me. The results are invariable:

> ts0 : 2144 /  ts1 : 2144 /  tw0 : 1489 /  tw1 :
> 1489 /  1944 Grand écran

Comment: probable duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1248081/how-to-get-the-browser-viewport-dimensions

Comment: Thanks Vinicius Katata. I've already seen this post in my research. But it applies to a javascript script. I've already used the screen.width and window.innerWidth functions in this context and it works. It's in the React context that it gets stuck.